# Windows Search Box on XFCE

Tags: windows, xfce, search, plugins, xfce-panel

I am trying to replicate Windows on Ubuntu Focal. I cannot find any equivalents for a XFCE panel plugin. I am trying to look as close as this:
[image: This]
and
[image: this].

Comment: You can try `synapse` as it has just about all of those searches, and it is able to search the internet as well.

Answer (score 0):

Besides trying `synapse` you can also use the `Whisker Menu` that already comes with Xfce4 (Xubuntu) to search your apps and launch a web search for you.  This isn't exactly like the Windows search but I think it will help with stuff you already have.

Whisker Menu:

[image]

To set up the Web / Google Search part do the following:

1. Right-click on the Whisker Menu and select Properties.

[image]

2. Click on the Search Actions tab.

[image]

3. Click on the `+` for Add Actions

[image]

4. Create Google Search

[image]

This is what I used for mine (but you can use any search engine you want as long as you use the `%u` at the end for the results you are looking for):

```
Name: Google Search
Pattern: ?
Command: exo-open --launch WebBrowser https://www.google.com/search?q=%u
```

5. Search menu for apps.  (I used theme as example)

[image]

6. Create Google Search in Search Box by starting with `?` and press enter for results.

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!